# Are questions about a web series on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

The definition of a [web series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_series) according to Wikipedia is:

> a series of scripted or non-scripted videos, generally in episodic form, released on the Internet and part of the newly emerging medium called web television.

Some of these, such as *[Dr. Horrible's Sing-Along Blog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Horrible%27s_Sing-Along_Blog)* (directed by Joss Whedon), are professionally produced and eventually got released to DVD as well.

Are these "web television" shows on topic?

Comment: TL;DR... yes, they are fine if they're sufficiently professionally produced.